# Using NServiceBus with an ASMX web service

Tags: asmx, nservicebus

I have legacy code base running a .Net 4.8 ASMX web service (not WCF based). I need to send messages using NServiceBus, but I cannot find a way to resolve any of the NServiceBus objects that I need (ITransactionalSession, IMessageSession). This is straightforward in a modern application using DI, but I am stuck in legacy land where that is non-existent. Ideally, I want to also take advantage of features like the outbox and transactional messaging to prevent ghost messages and zombie records.

I found [this example](https://www.davidboike.dev/2011/11/robust-3rd-party-integrations-with-nservicebus/) from David Boike (a developer at Particular), but it is over 12 years (and 6 versions) old, so I'm hesitant to follow it too closely. I am still reviewing it to see what I can glean, but I'm hoping that this community can provide some more up-to-date suggestions.

I am currently pulling in NSB 8.x (the most recent), but I would be willing to consider downgrading to a previous version if it supports .asmx services better while still minimizing any security considerations.

Update: Thanks to Dennis pointing out self-hosting below, I found [Externally Managed Mode](https://docs.particular.net/samples/dependency-injection/externally-managed-mode/) which allows me to create the service collection and manage its lifetime. I think this sample is still non-transactional (i.e. no transactional session/outbox support), and I do not understand why the message session is registered as a singleton instead of as a scoped dependency.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
const string endpointName = "MyEndpoint";
var endpoint = new EndpointConfiguration(endpointName);
// ... other configurations
var persistence = endpoint.UsePersistence<SqlPersistence>();
persistence.SqlDialect<SqlDialect.MsSqlServer>();
persistence.ConnectionBuilder(() => new SqlConnection(connectionString));
persistence.EnableTransactionalSession();
endpoint.EnableOutbox();

var services = new ServiceCollection();
var startable = EndpointWithExternallyManagedContainer.Create(endpoint, services);
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(new ServiceProviderOptions
            {
                ValidateOnBuild = true
            });

services.AddSingleton(p => startable.MessageSession.Value);
_endpointInstance = startable.Start(serviceProvider).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Is there anything wrong with registering the MessageSession as a scoped dependency? Or am I incorrect in my assumption that it would need to be a scoped dependency to support a transactional session/outbox?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for "[self hosting](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/#self-hosting)". You'll end up with an `IMessageSession` that you can store somewhere or have it injected in places where you want it.

Comment: Thanks Dennis - I think that gets me 90% of the way there. Reading through the self-hosting docs, I found [externally managed mode](https://docs.particular.net/samples/dependency-injection/externally-managed-mode/) which I think does what I need. I do not yet understand why the IMessageSession is being registered as a singleton in the code sample under "Configuring the Endpoint". I expected it to be registered as scoped instead.

I will add some additional information to the original question now that I have a handhold.